# asynchronous curl request after form posted and redirected back

Tags: php, curl, asynchronous

I have to run curl right after submitting and saving post data into database.
When the form data is saved i run curl and redirect to form again.

Is it possible to redirect without waiting for curl to complete?
Because in my case curl may take more then a minute.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You could make use of an `exec` fork

```
exec('php /path/to/your/curlscript.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

The `/dev/null 2>&1` & does not log anything and the `>` after your **`curlscript.php`** means it wont wait for anything.

Comment: i tried exec('php curl/file_1.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &'); 
i have windows,apache does this work on windows

Comment: Yes it does works on windows. Can you turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and let know what is your error ?

Comment: i have already error_reporting(E_ALL); error reporting on. but there is no error

Comment: Maybe it executed successfully.. This command won't output anything. It just forks the curl execution.

Comment: i have two files file_1.php contains code for writing file 

$file = fopen('abc.txt','w');
fwrite($file,'i am dummy content '.date('h:i s').'<br />');
fclose($file);

and other is $file_2.php have code 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
exec('php c:/wapm/www/curl/file_1.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &');

Comment: You mentioned `exec('php c:/wapm` shouldn't it be `wamp` instead of `wapm` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to call the page without cURL, using just javascript in async mode (for example - but depends on which kind of project are you working to).

For example

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#submit-button').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',   
            url: 'your-url.php',   
            data: $('#your-form').serialize(),
            success: success,
            dataType: dataType 
        });

        window.location.replace("your-next-page");
    });
});
```

Pay attention that in this way you'll not be notified of errors while storing the data...

Comment: i tried this, but first this is i have to make cross domain ajax, and other thing is redirection happens while running ajax, the ajax request will not be completed.

Comment: It's hard to give a working answer if we don't know whats the full "working stack"... Try to give some details more, I think we can find a solution.