# PHP: Right process to avoid timeout issue

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I have a PHP website and one of the pages I use makes a CURL call to another server. Now this server need about 45 seconds to respond, and there is nothing I can do about it.There is actually 2 step to get the information, the first step is to send the request to update the information (this takes about 43 seconds) and after I need to send another request to get the data back (normally takes 2-5 sec).

My server is on GoDaddy and obviously sometimes it timeout (CGI Timeout) because I think it's normally 30 seconds.

This script (asking the request + getting the data back), is normally triggered overnight via cron job however it can be triggered during the day.

So I was wondering: what would be the best way to split the information to avoid timeout issues?

I was thinking of just sending theupdate request and don't care about the result. Then, about a minute after, I would send a request to get back the data. However, I have no idea if it's even possible to do a timer in PHP, and if so, would the page timeout anyways?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to see if this will work on your server: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20797579/316900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a timeout value in your PHP code to allow more time.

[Setting Curl's Timeout in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582057/setting-curls-timeout-in-php)

If you want to run the files separately, I would set up a separate cron job for the second file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is not with the PHP file but with the CGI Timeout... I already use set_time_limit(120);

Comment: Have you increased the CURLOPT timeout settings? I have updated the link in my answer.

Comment: Yes, also did that,(See below)

Comment: If it is shared hosting, looks like you don't have the ability to increase the timeout. Have you tried this on a different server to verify it works so you can pinpoint it to the GoDaddy server?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did contact GoDaddy and they told me exactly this (cannot increase timeout). I did not try it on a different server. I was more trying to find a solution other then paying for a dedicated server :)

Comment: I understand. Sorry for the bad news.

Answer (score 0):

Use         CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT      to increase server response time.

```
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT
```

The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect. Use 0 to wait indefinitely.

And then you need to use CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to get working the option CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT.

Something like this,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); // 0 for wait infinitely, not a good practice

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //in seconds
```

You can set it in micro seconds as well , like so,

```
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS
```

Comment: Thanks but I already have those two lines in the script:`<pre> <code>
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120); //timeout in second
</code></pre>`

Comment: What about php time limit   set_time_limit(0);?